# Why does NSData remain nil after loading from a valid URL?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{   
    __strong IBOutlet UIImageView *testImageView;
}

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/79790000/jpg/_79790768_hi024951574.jpg"]];
    // imageData => nil ???
    testImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData: imageData]];

}

@end
```

I don't understand why `imageData` remains nil, even though the url exists.  Is it because I am doing this from the simulator?  Thanks

**UPDATE:**

[image]
Not entirely sure why I am getting a `NSFileReadUnknownError = 256`

Comment: There is another method that will return an error object as well; https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:

Comment: After `initWithContentsOfURL:` add: `NSLog(@"imageData length: %d, data: %@", imageData.length, [imageData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 300)]);` and you should see that the data is not nil, it is not for me ad I copied your statement. Output: "imageData length: 82454,
data: <ffd8ffe0 00104a46 49460001 0101006 ...". The next statements is best broken into two statements ignored to find the error. Compound statements are really not a good idea.

Comment: Otherwise use Charles Proxy to see exactly what, is sent and received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying the code you provided, I've got no problem with showing the image.

Looks like the issue lays in your local network environment.

I know it might sound dumb, but I encourage you to **reset and restart iOS simulator**. I've experienced a **bug that prevents simulator from properly connecting after sleeping and waking up Mac**. Xcode 6.1, Yosemite.

Also, please check if you're connecting through proxy or if your `/etc/hosts` file is clear regarding *bbcimg.co.uk* domain. Just the usual, sanity check.

Comment: Thank you so much. I restarted the simulator and it works! :)

Comment: Good one. +1. Learnt something.

Comment: Nice, glad to help. I've emphasized the correct solution. Hope that Xcode 6.2 will have that issue fixed.

Answer (score 0):

When you're dealing with the web services you need permissions for the transporation of your arbitrary load.
JUST follow the steps below:
1. GO to p.list>rightClick>OpenAs>SourceCode
2. paste the below lines into our p.list source code:
  (Find in attached image)[image]
3. Run your program & its done.